# Finding out what unicode characters are supported by a font in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, fonts, .net-2.0

I need something that can provide the information GetFontUnicodeRanges provides, but I can't find anything similar. I have to create a charmap-like control that will be used in a larger project. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what you'll need to pinvoke.  Graphics.GetHdc() gets you a device context handle.  Font.ToHfont() gets you a font handle.  Pinvoke SelectObject to select the font into the device context and its ready for use.  Be sure to restore everything when you're done.  Visit pinvoke.net for the declarations you'll need.

Comment: My boss wanted me to write a class in managed C++ that does that using GDI, and returns font ranges as a collection of value classes. The explanation he gave me is that "pinvoke sucks". Is there any practical reason for preferring this over using pinvoke?

Comment: You mean other than this being the guy that pays your bills?  Yeah, it will definitely look cleaner and much harder to get it wrong.  Deploying it is however a much bigger headache.